# How setwidth on all widgets of same type in UiApp? Like all textbox width = 100?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've written long script created UiApp. I didn't setWidth on any textboxes.

Can I change the UiApp default width for textboxes?

Or iterate through all textboxes to setwidth?

Unsure how do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no global method that would change the default UiApp textBox, the best you can do is to define a {style object} and use `setAttributes(style object)` to all your textBox widgets when you create them.

Comment: Thanks Serge ... I thought that likely.